# C: reverse of a string: res[i] = *p--; works, but *res++ = *p--; does not

Tags: c, pointers

In the below code to reverse a string in C language, it works when I access the string using the index, res[i] = *p--;

```
char *reverseString(char * s){
int l = strlen(s);
char *res = malloc(sizeof(s) + 1);
char *p = s + l - 1;    // point to the last letter
int i = 0;
for(;i < l; i++)
    res[i] = *p--;
return res;}
```

But when I use the following instead -

```
char *reverseString(char * s){
int l = strlen(s);
char *res = malloc(sizeof(s) + 1);
char *p = s + l - 1;    // point to the last letter
int i = 0;
for(;i < l; i++)
    *res++ = *p--;
return res;}
```

I get an empty string as the return value.

And res++ = *p--; inside the for() loop results in an error:

```
char *reverseString(char * s){
int l = strlen(s);
char *res = malloc(sizeof(s) + 1);
char *p = s + l - 1;    // point to the last letter
int i = 0;
for(;i < l; i++)
    res++ = *p--;
return res;}

 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   res++ = *p--;
         ^
```

I know it is a very basic question, but can someone please help me understand this?
Thank you.

Comment: at end of function `res` doesn't point to top of string.

Comment: res is the pointer, *res or res[i] is the value.

Comment: Saying "when I use the following instead - *res++ = *p--; I get an empty string as the return string" is not good enough. You need to show the entire function.

Comment: @KenWhite The first example is also incorrect. :-)

Comment: .... for multiple reasons, `sizeof(s)` being only one of them.

Comment: You need to `malloc` `l+1` bytes, not `sizeof(s)+1` bytes.  You also need to NUL terminate the result string, and return a pointer to the start, rather than the end of the result!

Comment: _lvalue required as left operand of assignment_ meant like `(pointer + 0) = address`. The left side is the result of the calculation and can not be assigned to it in C.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are modifying `res` and hence returning address of the end of the string character. You need to return the address of the memory block you have allocated.

```
char *reverseString(char * s)
{
    int l = strlen(s);
    char *res = malloc(l + 1); //As suggested by BLUEPIXY. It will be optimal.
    char *origAddr = res; //Store the original address of the memory block.
    char *p = s + l - 1;    // point to the last letter
    int i = 0;
    printf("Allocated addr: res[%p]\n", res);
    for(;i < l; i++){
        *res++ = *p--;
        printf("addr: res[%p]\n", res);
    }
    *res = '\0'; //As suggested by BLUEPIXY to terminate the string.

    return origAddr; /* Return the original address. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. But I still do not understand why res++ = *p-- won't work and throw the error?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks I see the problem now.

Comment: @DeeptiSabnani: res is a address variable. When you do `res++ = *p-- `, you are assigning to variable 'res'. If you want to access the actual memory, you need to put `*`.

Comment: Why are you calling `strlen` twice on the same string?